# Why can't I use "." as a delimiter in split() function?

Tags: java, exception, xls, delimiter, indexoutofboundsexception

I have to take an input file, and append a number at the end to its name to use as output file. To achieve this, I use the following code:

```
String delimiter = ".";
String[] splitInput = inputLocation.split(delimiter);
String outputLocation = splitInput[0];
```

and I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

I added the following statement to check the length of the splitInput array, and I get 0 as output.

```
System.out.println(splitInput.length);
```

Later, I used ".x" as delimiter (my file being .xls). I can use ".x" and achieve my purpose but I'm curious why won't "." work?

Comment: try using "\." instead. I'm not in a place where I can check it, but  I think that split expects a regex, and the . character represents any character.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, thanks. I got my answer there..

Comment: @Kylar, My filename is like c:/temp/sample.xsl.. I needed the c:/temp/sample and add a number like 123 and then add .xls to it.
Initially I thought I could just split into two parts around the . , and add the number in middle.. Now I split using ".x" and get the first part, add the number and have the extension hard-coded. Thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `split` function uses regular expressions, you have to escape your "." with a "\"

When using regular expressions a "." means any character. Try this

```
String delimiter = "\\.x";
```

It should also be mentioned that `\` in java is also a special character used to create other special characters. Therefore you have to escape your `\` with another `\` hence the  `"\\.x"`

---

Theres some great documentation in the Java docs about all the special characters and what they do:

[Java 8 Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
[Java 7 Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
[Java 6 Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 2):

The `.` has a special meaning: Any character (may or may not match line terminators). You can escape it prepending `\`  or use:

```
[.]x
```

e.g.:

```
String delimiter = "[.]x";
```

See more in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

`.` is considered as any character in regex. Please use escape character `\` (which also needs to be escaped as `\\`), if you want to override the special meaning of it.

Answer (score 1):

`String.split()` expects a regex as input. In Java regexes, `.` character is a special character. Thus, your split statement is not working the way you expected. You should escape your "." as `\\.`.